# iOS Possible to set a blend mode on UILabel?

Tags: ios, ios5, uilabel

Say for example you have some text put in programmatically like this:

```
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 10, 254, 100)];
[myLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SomeFont" size:76]];
[myLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.227451 green:0.666667 blue:1 alpha:0.9]];
```

Is there a way to apply a blend mode on the text? Say for example Color Dodge?

Comment: Can you explain a little what you mean with "apply a blend mode on the text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

If you have a fixed background, you could do this by creating a custom view subclass and implementing the drawRect method yourself and using CGContext methods to set the blend mode and draw the string.

But you can't use blending *between* views (except alpha blending), so this kind of blending only works if you set the background manually in the drawRect. It can't be done if your view background is transparent.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the quick response.